# Como obtener un campo de una tabla en el select de otra si el campo se repite 3 veces

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, join, null

Tengo una tabla llamadas planesvivos, la cual guarda puros índices de otras tablas (personas, estados, municipios, localidades).

La tabla planesvivos tiene lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estoy haciendo un select para mostrar los nombres en vez de los índices. para lo cual cree la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT `planesvivos`.`id`,
  `personas`.`nombre` AS `productor`, 
  `estados`.`nombre` AS `estado`,
  `municipios`.`nombre` AS `municipio`,
  `localidades`.`nombre` AS `localidad`, 
  `personas2`.`nombre` AS `asesor`,
  `personas3`.`nombre` AS `evaluador`,
  `planesvivos`.`mapabase`,
  `planesvivos`.`notas`, 
  `planesvivos`.`estatus`
FROM `planesvivos` 
LEFT JOIN `personas` ON `personas`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`productor` 
LEFT JOIN `estados` ON `estados`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`estado` 
LEFT JOIN `municipios` ON `municipios`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`municipio` 
LEFT JOIN `localidades` ON `localidades`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`localidad` 
LEFT JOIN `personas` `personas2` ON `personas`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`asesor` 
LEFT JOIN `personas` `personas3` ON `personas`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`evaluador`
```

Pero no funciona, ya que no me muestra los valores de asesor y evaluador. El resultado de la consulta anterior me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema está en los campos asesor y evaluador. Cabe mencionar que cree las claves foráneas correspondientes en la tabla planesvivos. Si no no pudiera obtener los datos de productor, estado, municipio y localidad.

Alguien puede orientarme en cómo debería ser la consulta para que me devuelva los valores correspondientes? Gracias

EDIT1: La tabla personas si tiene registros en los indices 6 y 8.
Cambíe los valores de asesor y evaluador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahora la consulta me regresa lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

ya lo resolvi con ayuda de otro amigo desarrollador: he aqui la solución por si a alguien más le sirve:

```
SELECT
a.id,
b.nombre as productor, 
c.nombre as estado,
d.nombre as municipio,
e.nombre as localidad, 
f.nombre as asesor,
g.nombre as evaluador,
a.mapabase,
a.notas, 
a.estatus
FROM planesvivos as a
LEFT JOIN personas as b ON a.productor=b.id
LEFT JOIN estados as c ON  a.estado=c.id
LEFT JOIN municipios as d ON a.municipio=d.id
LEFT JOIN localidades as e ON a.localidad =e.id
LEFT JOIN personas as f ON a.asesor = f.id
LEFT JOIN personas as g ON a.evaluador=g.id
```

El problema estaba en que no estaba tomando el nombre de la tabla personas2 ni personas3 en la consulta anterior, por eso no mandaba el valor.

Comment: ¿Y has visto lo que habías hecho mal en tu consulta? Lo interesante de SO no es obtener la solución si no ver qué haces mal y aprender de tus errores... Por otra parte, recuerda que una respuesta sin explicaciones es considerada de baja calidad. En consecuencia, te animo a completar tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La consulta tiene buen aspecto, tal vez el problema está en que no existen los `id` 6 y 8 en la tabla `personas` y por eso obtienes sendos `NULL`.

Prueba con un:

```
INSERT INTO personas (id,nombre) VALUES
  (6,'Juan (evaluador)'),
  (8,'Pedro (asesor)');
```

Y, si no te funciona, modifica la pregunta incluyendo tu dataset en SQL, que obtienes desde phpMyAdmin->Exportar, y así podremos ver qué hay en tu base de datos y probar tu consulta con datos reales.

### Edición a partir del dataset

A la vista de que esos registros existían y revisando la consulta, se puede apreciar cómo, aunque se define un alias para las distintas combinaciones de la tabla `personas`, se continúa utilizando su nombre original en vez del alias. De ahí que no localice los registros. Con este simple cambio se habría subsanado el error de la consulta original:

```
SELECT `planesvivos`.`id`,
  `personas`.`nombre` AS `productor`, 
  `estados`.`nombre` AS `estado`,
  `municipios`.`nombre` AS `municipio`,
  `localidades`.`nombre` AS `localidad`, 
  `personas2`.`nombre` AS `asesor`,
  `personas3`.`nombre` AS `evaluador`,
  `planesvivos`.`mapabase`,
  `planesvivos`.`notas`, 
  `planesvivos`.`estatus`
FROM `planesvivos` 
LEFT JOIN `personas` ON `personas`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`productor` 
LEFT JOIN `estados` ON `estados`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`estado` 
LEFT JOIN `municipios` ON `municipios`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`municipio` 
LEFT JOIN `localidades` ON `localidades`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`localidad` 
LEFT JOIN `personas` `personas2` ON `personas2`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`asesor` 
LEFT JOIN `personas` `personas3` ON `personas3`.`id` = `planesvivos`.`evaluador`
```

Obteniendo, para el dataset aportado:

```
1   HUMBERTO JIMENEZ JIMENEZ    Chiapas VILLA CORZO BONANZA HUMBERTO JIMENEZ JIMENEZ    DELMAR ALONSO YAÑEZ GOMEZ   archivo1.jpg    nota1   1
2   DELMAR ALONSO YAÑEZ GOMEZ   Chiapas BERRIOZABAL EL TIROL    DELMAR ALONSO YAÑEZ GOMEZ   HUMBERTO JIMENEZ JIMENEZ    archivo2.jpg    nota2   1
```